# How to fix Dokan to implement a Virtual Drive?

Tags: windows, device-driver, device-emulation, dokan, virtualfilesystem

Dokan currently does not create a virtual hard disk for its filesystem (i.e. in Device manager, you dont see another disk drive). Anyone have any idea on how to start to correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dokany is the active fork of Dokan and bring the ability to create virtual drive.

Dokany have made big progress by implementing the mount manager of dokan. There is only the PnP part that is not totally implemented. When this will be added, you will see the dokan device in the device manager.

Answer (score 0):

Representation in device manager requires a plug-n-play device driver. so you need to write one. Or use our Callback File System